# Java printDialog() when deployed on linux machine not working(no popup)

Tags: java, linux, pdfbox, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

I am using `Apache wicket 6.19.0`, `pdfbox 1.8.8`, and `Java 8`.
The problem I am facing is I get the print dialog on screen when I deploy my application on a `Windows` machine, but when deployed on the `Linux` server it doesn't show the print dialog on screen when invoked the print functionality from UI.

Code:

```
public static PrintService choosePrinter() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    if(printJob.printDialog()) {
        return printJob.getPrintService();          
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public File getObject() {
    File file = new File("document.pdf");
    file.deleteOnExit();
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    //prepare the pdf here...
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PrintService service = choosePrinter();
    if(service != null){
        job.setPrintService(service);
        document.silentPrint(job);
    }
    document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception: "+e);
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PrinterJob is a class from AWT, i.e. a desktop feature.
You cannot use it at the server. 
Apache Wicket is a web framework so I assume your users will reach the application thru a browser. In this case you have two options:

1. render a good looking HTML and use JavaScript's `window.print()` to print it
2. render a PDF and stream it to the browser so that it either:

   2.1. show it by using `Content-Disposition: Inline` response header (if the browser has PDF plugin)

   2.2. ask the user to save it, by using `Content-Disposition: Attachment`

I am not sure whether there is a way to print the PDF with JavaScript.

Comment: so, you mean to say that the printDialog wont work with Linux? and will work with Windows?

Comment: No. I'm saying that it will work on localhost but it won't work at the server. At localhost you have a desktop UI (aka 'X' in Linux) while usually at the server  you don't have it. Even if PrinterJob works at the server (with running X and properly exported $DISPLAY env) it will show the dialog at the server, not at the user's machine.